# Unable to run Interrupt function in code not working

Tags: pic, microchip, mplab, xc8

Having problems with this part of the code: `void interrupt ISR_Timer0_Int`

mplabs x ide 5.10 show error:

> newmain.c:26:6: error: variable has incomplete type 'void'
>   newmain.c:26:15: error: expected ';' after top level declarator

I am using XC8 V2 compiler and it is going into a PIC18f4550

**Code:**

```
void interrupt ISR_Timer0_Int()  // Timer0 Interrupt Service Routine (ISR)
{
    if (INTCONbits.TMR0IF) // TMR0IF:- Timer0 Overflow Interrupt Flag Bit
        // 1 = TMR0 reg has overflowed
        // 0 = TMR0 reg has not overflowed
    {
        TMR0H = 0xED; // Timer0 start value = 0x48E5 for 0.1 second
        TMR0L = 0x4C;
        if (j <= 7) { //limit up to 7

            j++; // Increase count by 1
            PORTD = j; // Output to Demultiplexer

        }
        else {

            j = 0; // Reset count aftwr it hit 7
            PORTD = j; // Output to Demultiplexer

        }
        INTCONbits.TMR0IF = 0; // Reset TMR0IF to "0" since the end of
        // the interrupt function has been reached
    }
}
```

Comment: Mayabe a problem with the further code in the file newmain.c. Could you show more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax changed with the new compiler. More info on this and links to the documentation can be found here https://www.microforum.cc/topic/5-i-used-to-use-to-locate-variables-but-since-xc8-20-this-is-no-longer-working/

You can get your old code to compile as explained in that link by setting the compiler back to C90 mode or by
 using the new interrupt syntax.